# Flutter : SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error after reCAPTCHA:

`E/FirebaseAuth(22392): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39`

My Debug/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--    package="com.manshore.mosaic_doctors">-->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
    </manifest>
```

My Main :

```
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();
  await Global.initializeSharedPreferences();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  String? phoneNum = Global.prefs!.getString("phoneNo");
  print("phoneNum $phoneNum");
  await LabDatabase.getDoctorInfo(phoneNum ??"");

  //AuthService.signOut();

  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, body: EntryPoint()),
    ),
  ));
}
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
name: mosaic_doctors
description: MOSAIC doctors app
publish_to: 'none'
version: 4.2.3+423

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.5
  get: ^4.3.8
  intl: 0.17.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  jiffy: 4.0.0
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.0.2
  printing: ^5.2.1
  #flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  linked_scroll_controller: ^0.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.2
  loading_overlay: ^0.3.0
  pdf: ^3.5.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  encrypt: ^5.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  get_it: ^7.6.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2
  path_provider: any
  #  open_file: ^3.0.3
  open_file_safe: any

  permission_handler: 11.0.1
  marquee: ^2.2.0
  reviews_slider: ^2.0.0
  date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
  checkbox_grouped: 2.0.0
  file_picker: 3.0.0
  country_picker: 2.0.21
  country_currency_pickers: ^3.0.0
  dio: ^5.2.1+1
  path: ^1.6.4
  sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2
  smart_select: ^4.3.2
  webview_flutter: ^2.3.1
  barcode_widget: ^2.0.4
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.0
  google_sign_in_dartio: ^0.2.2+1 # For Windows support
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.13.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.4.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.1.0
  firebase_database: ^10.1.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

google-services.json:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "690646858547",
    "firebase_url": "https://mosaic-doctors.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "mosaic-doctors",
    "storage_bucket": "mosaic-doctors.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:690646858547:android:655323ff14654eb01f5c46",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.manshore.mosaic_doctors"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "690646858547-9qkns779evdlijk7nfmfttufp6e6cjpj.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.manshore.mosaic_doctors",
            "certificate_hash": "17cc84630f20835f097d94434d16c22ef79e1daf"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "690646858547-e8li5otp2cq72ii9vtljv4i19tla01n1.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.manshore.mosaic_doctors",
            "certificate_hash": "bb0d9922a38daf9bc65ca25c3fea9c7c299c875c"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "690646858547-ltfr1l55labvk6584a8f7penikg80j65.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.manshore.mosaic_doctors",
            "certificate_hash": "c69b382d1e50ae8d07d923bd1b880202f65fb512"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "690646858547-f4rhugs8d6r1b83nej6fdquupc3ru9lk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyDprKD9o8ihFwm5dMl6Deo6vBswfK5FyhA"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "690646858547-f4rhugs8d6r1b83nej6fdquupc3ru9lk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "690646858547-1s0m8dll76vhm4rvb40ulpa2cd22ip0m.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.manshore.mosaicDoctors"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
android {

    compileSdkVersion 33
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
//            storeFile file("key2.jks")
//            storePassword "keystore3"
//            keyAlias "key"
//            keyPassword "keystore3"
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(8)
    }

    android.lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true //false
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.manshore.mosaic_doctors"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    namespace "com.manshore.mosaic"
}








flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
}
tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`Flutter version :3.13.0 stable Gradle version: 8.0.2`

What i've tried :
Every answer on Stackoverflow
Every answer on GitHub
Every answer on reddit
Physical device and emulator
Different phone numbers
Different versions on almost every plugin